# Insert Image using FPDF.js

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I've started using [FPDF.js](https://github.com/rx4hvn/fpdf). It's the extended library of [jsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf).

There's a well written code for inserting images using jsPDF

```
var imgData = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/sad,flkhaskdfjh"; //this base64 is just an example
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(35, 25, "Paranyan loves jsPDF");
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
```

But I want to insert the same using FPDF. How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

Not possible unless you save the file to disk first or it is available via a link. You cannot insert a image from a base64 string using standard FPDF.

Comment: Any idea how to insert image via link or after saving the file to disk. Would be a a great help. Thanks